# Exiting "for" loop too soon yielding inaccurate count

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, file-handling

In my program, I am iterating through lines in a .txt file. I am adding these lines to a dictionary depending on if they begin with a text or numeric value. Between instances of numeric lines, I want to count the number of lines with strings that occur. I also add both the numeric line's content and string line count to a dictionary.

My file looks something like this:
6/10/21
string
string
string
6/11/21

However, I exit the loop too early and I'm not sure why. For example, my program would only count two lines of strings instead of three. Here's some of my code:

```
    count = 0
    for i in myfile:
      if i[0].isdigit():
        s = i.strip()
        my_dict["Numeric"].append(s)
      if i[0].isdigit()==False:
        count = count + 1
        next_ln = next(myfile)
        if next_ln[0].isdigit():
          print(next_ln)
          my_dict["String Count"].append(count)
          count = 0
```

In another version of my code, I have the final if-statement aligned with the others but it doesn't change anything. Sorry if this has been asked before or if this is a really obvious problem, but I couldn't find anything that helped resolve my issue.

Comment: well you're using the `next()` function within the loop which will read the next line of the file. the for loop already uses the `next()` function to get the next line from the file (and store it in the `i` variable) in every iteration. kindly avoid using `next()` within the for loop.

Comment: i fail to understand the use of `count` variable here.. could you explain a bit more?

Comment: is there an acceptable way to look at the next line without using next() because I'm not sure how to preserve the logic I want by just iterating?

Comment: also, the count variable is used to count how many strings occur between instances of numbers

Comment: there is a way, to avoid using next, by appending the value 0 whenever you encounter a numeric line, and incrementing the last item of the list by 1 whenever a string line is encountered. please wait, im posting my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `my_dict["String Count"]` is the list of count of string lines, and `my_dict["Numeric"]` the list of numeric lines.

The goal here is to avoid the use of `next()` within the for-loop, as that is messing up the functioning of the for-loop, and hence giving you undesired results.

Here's my solution:

```py
for i in myfile:
    if i[0].isdigit():
        s = i.strip()
        my_dict["Numeric"].append(s)
        
        # initiating a new element 0 to the count list
        my_dict["String Count"].append(0)
    else:
        # incrementing the value of the last present number in the count list by 1
        my_dict["String Count"][-1] += 1
```

Here I've also assumed that whatever doesn't start numerically, is a string line. You may make the necessary modifications to the `else` clause into an `elif` or any other condition you want.

The end result is that, every numeric line in `my_dict["Numeric"]` will have a corresponding number (at the same index) in the `my_dict["String Count"]` containing the number of string lines that comes after it.

Comment: Your assumption for my_dict is correct, thank you, this fixed everything!

Comment: Happy to assist!